# Remove automatic closing on ModalPopupExtender

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender

Is there a way that I can remove the automatic closing on ModalPopupExtender after saving?

This is my current code.

```
<ajaxtoolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="UpdateButton" PopupControlID="pnlPopup"
                BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBackground" CancelControlID="btnCancel"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modelpopup properties to remove automatic closing.

**OkControlID** - The ID of the element that dismisses the modal popup

**OnOkScript** - Script to run when the modal popup is dismissed with the OkControlID